# Add more small talk options into Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am utilising the small talk options within the chatbot that I currently use, however, I have noticed a couple of common questions which seem to be asked which fit into small talk, such as "What is your name?" and "What does you name mean?".

Is there any way in which I can add to the list of small talk questions? If not, how can I add these questions in with their responses? My issue is that I believe that you shall need a new intent for every question that gets asked? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a new intent for every question asked (or at least different versions of the same question with one answer) is the standard Dialogflow design and isn't really a problem.

The small talk functionality is just a big list of questions and answers in separate intents - you can see by looking at the pre built small talk agent through Prebuilt Agents -> Small Talk -> Import.

Therefore I would suggest to simply do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, small-talk option had this issue which you specified here where users were not able to add more phrases to existing questions or add more questions.
To solve this issue, DialogFlow has introduced **Small Talk Pre-built Agen**t.

There are approx 86 pre-built intents in the small-talk agent.

- You can add/modify the phrases in those intents,
- You can add/delete intents
- You can modify the responses of these intents

To use small-talk agent, go to `pre-built agents` option in left menu, go to `Small Talk` agent, then **import** it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use QnA maker service to achieve the functionality. Basically you have to create a QnA maker service and have to integrate to Bot. It will resolve your query. Please let us know if you need more information .

Regards,
Tharak